# MySQL worckbench create a view

Tags: mysql, view

```
create view `first_view` as 
SELECT * from `database`.pesho
where id<5 or (name != 'sad' and id >100)
order by name,age desc
```

Error message:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmPL9.jpg So it says "no database selected", but how do i select a table in all of the tutorials i have come by, thats what all this guys are doing.

Comment: database=your_database_name i.e your schema name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to told `MySQL` that use this database and then only execute this query.

Or

You can set default schema name and then execute this query.

```
USE database;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: `use databese;
create view first_view as 
SELECT * from `database`.pesho
where id<5 or (name != 'sad' and id >100)
order by name,age desc` returs unkown database database error code 1049

Comment: @ВсеЕдно `database` means what your schema name is. Here your mention `from database.pesho where id<5 ` so i thought `database` is your `schema` name

Comment: yes database is the schema name, it's the same as on the screenshot, haven't changed anything, it's wierd why it doesn't work

Comment: so the i fount out what was the problem. `database ` seems to be reserved somehow. With  `use minions;` instead it worked!! and it plased it  inside of that shema

Comment: @ВсеЕдно great...!! Keep it up.